# how to update label from my tableview, objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Here is I trying to update my label from tableview. I am doing something wrong, and can't grasp it. Label in different table view. So, I am trying to send data from table view to detail view controller

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TechStars.h"
#import "InfoViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.techstars = [TechStars stars];

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [self.techstars count];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return 80;
}

- (UIImage *)imageScaledToSize:(UIImage *)image size:(CGSize)newSize {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"employeeCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setNumberOfLines:0]; // unlimited number of lines
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize: 12.0]];

    NSDictionary *employee = self.techstars[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [employee objectForKey:@"employeename"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [employee objectForKey:@"position"];
    cell.imageView.image = [self imageScaledToSize :[employee objectForKey:@"profilePicture"] size:CGSizeMake(95, 75)];


    return cell;

}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
    {
        if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[InfoViewController class]])
        {
            InfoViewController *nextViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
            NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
            TechStars *selectedObject = [self.techstars objectAtIndex:path.row];
            // this also can be written as self.techstars[path.row]; literal syntax
            nextViewController.stars = selectedObject;
        }
    }
}


 InfoViewController.h
//  Test
//
//  Created by 123 on 10/07/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 123. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TechStars.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface InfoViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) TechStars *stars; 

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *employeeName;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *employeeImage;


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *employeeDuties;


@end


//  InfoViewController.m
//  Test
//
//  Created by 123 on 10/07/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 123. All rights reserved.
//

#import "InfoViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface InfoViewController ()

@end

@implementation InfoViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Where is performSegue called from?

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in `prepareForSegue`  to see what is happening?  Maybe your `if` statements aren't matching.  Also you don't seem to do anything with `stars` in the destination view controller

Comment: What label are you trying to update exactly? One of `InfoViewController`? Where? In `prepareForSegue:sender:`? If YES, it's because the `IBOulet UILabel` is still nil. You need to set the value into a `NSString` property of the `InfoViewController` and then assign its value to the `UILabel`.

Comment: Actually, I don't know to set equal my label to array from tableview? everything else I checked twice and it is ok

Comment: in `viewWillAppear` you can set `self.myLabel.text = ...`

Comment: Yes, i know, self.myLabel.text = and exactly I don't know to set equal array. my array is stars

Comment: You need to pass string or object to InfoViewController and then set value. Because IBOutlet UILabel is not allocated memory.

Comment: My object is stars, @property (strong, nonatomic) TechStars *stars

Comment: You seem to be a bit confused; in `cellForRowAtIndex` your  `self.techstars` contains `NSDictionary` but in `prepareForSegue` you say that it contains `TechStar` - If you table method is working, I guess it contains `NSDictionary`, in which case you should change `prepareForSegue` and the `stars` property to be `NSDictionary`.  Then you can say `self.myLabel.text = self.stars[@"employeename"]`

Comment: Make sure that the dictionary is allocated or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Please try the below code:
    -(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"secondView"])
        {
            UINavigationController* controller = [segue destinationViewController];
            NSArray *viewControllers = controller.viewControllers;
            SecondViewController* viewController = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

            NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
            TechStars *selectedObject = [self.techstars objectAtIndex:path.row];

            viewController.stars = selectedObject ;
        }
    }
```